# Moving Points and lines mapbox

Tags: javascript, gis, mapbox-gl-js

I am creating some mapping software with Mapbox GL JS. So far it has gotten a bit complex but everything is working how I intended except for moving features. The behavior is expected except in a few edge cases. It seems to happen when I am editing the point of a `LineString` with multiple points.

here is a link to a [gif](https://netgis.app/issue.gif) demonstrating my issue

**MoveFeatures.js**

```js
var editing_feature = null;
var moving_features = false;
var get_manipulated_coordinate_index_buffer = 5;
var click_buffer = 5;
var get_attached_lines_buffer = 5;
var manipulated = null;
var manipulated_sources_buffer_array = [];

var get_attached_lines = (point_feature) => {
    var point = window.MAP.mapbox.project(point_feature.geometry.coordinates);
    var buffer = get_attached_lines_buffer;
    var b = [window.MAP.mapbox.project([window.MAP.bounds.x, window.MAP.bounds.y]), window.MAP.mapbox.project([window.MAP.bounds.i, window.MAP.bounds.j])];
    var features = [];

    window.MAP.mapbox.queryRenderedFeatures([[point.x - buffer, point.y - buffer], [point.x + buffer, point.y + buffer]], {layers: ['lines']}).forEach((feature) => {
        features[feature.id] = feature;
    })
   

    var at = window.MAP.mapbox.queryRenderedFeatures(b, {layers: ['lines']}).filter((feature) => {
        return features[feature.id] !== undefined;
    })
    //console.log(at)
    return at
}

var get_manipulated_coordinate_index = (attached_lines, point_feature) => { //gets the index of the coordinates that is being manipulated in a LineString
    console.log(attached_lines)
    var point = window.MAP.mapbox.project(point_feature.geometry.coordinates);
    var buffer = get_manipulated_coordinate_index_buffer;
    var indexes = [];
    var pt1 = turf.polygon([[[point.x - buffer, point.y - buffer],[point.x + buffer, point.y - buffer],[point.x + buffer, point.y + buffer],[point.x - buffer, point.y + buffer],[point.x - buffer, point.y - buffer]]]);
    attached_lines.forEach((feature, i) => {
        feature.geometry.coordinates.forEach((coordinate, j) => {
            var converted = window.MAP.mapbox.project(coordinate);
            var pt = turf.point([converted.x, converted.y]);
            if(turf.booleanPointInPolygon(pt, pt1)){
                indexes.push({line_index:i, coordinate_index:j, source:window.MAP.mapbox.getSource(feature.source)})
            }
        })
    })
    return {indexes:indexes, lines:attached_lines};
}

export default {
    actions:[
        {
            event_type:'click',
            func: (e) => {
                var buffer = click_buffer;
                var feature = window.UTILS.get_clicked_point(e);
                window.UTILS.toggle_point_highlight(feature);
                if(!moving_features){
                    if(feature != null){
                        moving_features = true;
                        editing_feature = window.MAP.mapbox.getSource(feature.properties.s_uid + '_hovered')._data.features.filter((f) => { return f.id == feature.id })[0];
                        manipulated = get_manipulated_coordinate_index(get_attached_lines(editing_feature), editing_feature);
                    }
                }else{
                    editing_feature = null;
                    manipulated = null;
                    manipulated_sources_buffer_array = [];
                    moving_features = false;
                }
            }
        },
        {
            event_type:'mousemove',
            func: (e) => {
                if(moving_features){
                    manipulated.lines.forEach((feature, i) => {
                        var f = feature;
                        if(manipulated.indexes[i] !== undefined){
                            f.geometry.coordinates[manipulated.indexes[i].coordinate_index] = [e.lngLat.lng, e.lngLat.lat];
                        }
                        window.UTILS.update_feature(f);
                    })
                    editing_feature.geometry.coordinates = [e.lngLat.lng, e.lngLat.lat];
                    window.UTILS.update_feature(editing_feature);
                }
            }
        },
        {
            event_type:'disable',
            func: (e) => {
                window.UTILS.toggle_point_highlight(editing_feature);
                editing_feature = null;
                manipulated = null;
                manipulated_sources_buffer_array = [];
                moving_features = false;
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Utils.js**

```js
var debounced = [];

const UTILS = {
    rgb_to_hex: (rgb) => {
        rgb = rgb.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',')
        var r = parseInt(rgb[0]);
        var g = parseInt(rgb[1]);
        var b = parseInt(rgb[2]);
        return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
    },

    hex_to_rgb: (hex) => {
        if(hex[0] == '#'){
            hex = hex.slice(1);
        }
        return `rgb(${parseInt(hex.slice(1, 3), 16)}, ${parseInt(hex.slice(3, 5), 16)}, ${parseInt(hex.slice(5, 7), 16)})`;
    },

    get_clicked_point: (e) => {
        var buffer = 5;
        var symbol_hover_layers = window.MAP.loaded_images.map((image) => { return image + '_hovered' });
        var feature = window.MAP.mapbox.queryRenderedFeatures([[e.point.x - buffer, e.point.y - buffer], [e.point.x + buffer, e.point.y + buffer]], {layers:[...window.MAP.loaded_images, ...symbol_hover_layers] })[0];

        if(feature && feature.geometry.type == 'Point'){
            return  feature
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    },

    get_render_area(){
        var bounds = window.MAP.mapbox.getBounds();
        var topLeft = bounds.getNorthWest();
        var bottomRight = bounds.getSouthEast();
        return {x: topLeft.lng, y: topLeft.lat, i: bottomRight.lng, j: bottomRight.lat}
    },

    get_render_area2(){
        var render_area = window.UTILS.get_render_area();
        var start = window.MAP.mapbox.project([render_area.x, render_area.y]);
        var end = window.MAP.mapbox.project([render_area.i, render_area.j]);
        return [start, end]
    },

    debounce(func, timeout){
        if(window.debounce_timeout){
            clearTimeout(window.debounce_timeout);
        }
        window.debounce_timeout = setTimeout(func, timeout)
    },

    delete_feature(feature){
        var source = window.MAP.mapbox.getSource(feature.source);
        source._data.features = source._data.features.filter((f) => {
            return f.id !== feature.id;
        });
        source.setData(source._data);
    },

    update_feature(feature){
        this.delete_feature(feature);
        var source = window.MAP.mapbox.getSource(feature.source);
        source._data.features.push(feature);
        source.setData(source._data);
    },

    toggle_point_highlight(feature){
        if(feature){
            if(feature.properties.hover){
                this.unhighlight_point(feature);
            }else{
                this.highlight_point(feature);
            }
        }
    },

    highlight_point(feature){
        if(feature.geometry.type == 'Point'){
            this.delete_feature(feature);
            feature.properties.hover = true;
            var s = window.MAP.mapbox.getSource(feature.source + '_hovered');
            feature.source = feature.source + '_hovered';
            s._data.features.push(feature);
            s.setData(s._data);
        }
    },

    unhighlight_point(feature){
        if(feature.geometry.type == 'Point'){
            this.delete_feature(feature);
            feature.properties.hover = false;
            var s = window.MAP.mapbox.getSource(feature.source.replace('_hovered', ''));
            feature.source = feature.source.replace('_hovered', '');
            s._data.features.push(feature);
            s.setData(s._data);
        }
    }
}

export default UTILS;
```

Has anyone here implement feature manipulation in mapbox? What could I do differently to make this behave better? All i need to move is the points and the lines attached to them the rest of the lines should be maintained.